# How to prefetch message in ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, low-latency

Is there any way to receive multiple messages at once call recv in ZeroMQ like in rabbitmq? I don't find any document mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *Is there **any way** to receive multiple messages at once call recv in ZeroMQ like in rabbitmq?*

No, there is not.

Unless you re-factor ZeroMQ Architecture to a principally new shape and fashion, so as to become more like a RabbitMQ.